# How to add the new / commands in discord and fix error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

Im making a discord bot to provide my paypal email and the ammount, the idea was if I put /paypal ammount: ammount here it will make an embed with the information. and it worked. But I cant figure out how to add the new / commands thing and it also only listens to my commands when I mention the bot. Other than that it wont reply to the message.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ''

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot is ready. Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def paypal(ctx, amount: float):
    total_amount = amount + (amount * 0.2)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Payment', color=discord.Color.blue())
    embed.add_field(name='Note', value='Send the amount to myemail@gmail.com as Friends and Family in USD (Do NOT add a note).', inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='PayPal Email', value='My email', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Amount', value=f'${total_amount}', inline=False)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/pp_cc_mark_37x23.jpg')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I tried it but I couldnt do it I would appreciate any help!!

Comment: do you mean slash command `/` or message command with prefix `/`?

Comment: Command not prefx

Comment: If you are using command, then you need a command prefix. If you are using slash command, the prefix is set to `/`.

Comment: Yeah Ik but I want it like the new discord stuff where if you just put /  it will show all the bots commands and have the new fill in shit like this: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1115209226017591337/1124372087734276218/image.png?width=1440&height=157

Comment: That's application commands, also called slash commands. You could read this gist written by AbstractUmbra to get some idea: https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f